# Determine all integral domains $D$ such that $d^5=d$, for all $d \in D$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-fields

**Additional information:** Knowing that finite fields must have $p^k$ elements, with $p$ prime and $k\geq1,k\in \mathbb{N}$. In the case of $k=1$, the field is $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

**Problem**: Determine all integral domains $D$ such that $d^5=d$, for all $d \in D$.

**My answer**: $D$ is an integral domain, so we can use the cancellation law for ring product, and then $d^5=d \Rightarrow d^4=1$, and therefore $d\neq 0$.
Factoring $d^4-1=0$ we have:
\begin{align*}
d^4-1 &= 0 \\
(d^2+1)(d^2-1) &= 0 \\
(d^2+1)(d+1)(d-1) &= 0
\end{align*}
Then $d=1$, $d=(-1)$, or $d^2=(-1)$. We have two options:

- $d^2\neq (-1)$: in this case we have $d=1=(-1)$ and $D=\{0,1\}\cong \mathbb{Z}_2$, or $d_1=1$, $d_2=(-1)$ and $D=\{0,1,-1\}\cong \mathbb{Z_3}$ (in both case is easy to prove that every element different from $0$ has an inverse, so $D$ is a finite field, and the isomorphism follows from the given additional information).
- $d^2=(-1)$: We have that the equation $d^2+1=0$ has at most two solutions in $D$. Let $a$ and $b$ be the solutions. Follows that $a^2=(-1)=b^2$ and therefore:
  \begin{align*}
  a^2-b^2 &= 0 \\
  (a+b)(a-b) &= 0 \Rightarrow a=b\lor a=-b
  \end{align*}

**(Here's where my doubt begins)**

If $b=1$ then $a=1$ or $a=(-1)$, in any case we fall into the integral domains already mentioned (same for $b=(-1)$), so suppose that $b\neq \pm 1$. Them $D = \{0,1,-1,b,-b\}\cong \mathbb{Z_5}$, because, suppose that $b=-b$. Then:
\begin{align*}
2b=0 & \Rightarrow b+b=0 \\
     & \Rightarrow b(1+1)=0b \\
     & \Rightarrow (1+1)=0 \\
     & \Rightarrow 1=-1 
\end{align*}
which is absurd. Is that right?

Comment: $1=-1$ isn't that absurd: It's true in $\mathbb{Z}_2$. So is there an integral domain where $1=-1$ and there is also one element $b$ with $b^2+1=0$?

Comment: From [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question): " **Your question should be clear without the title.** After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. **The title is not the first sentence of your question**, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title."

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you stumbled onto it:   there's $\Bbb Z_2$ as well.

One way to see it is that $x^5\equiv x\pmod2$ since $0,1$ both work.

So that gives us three: $\Bbb Z_5,\Bbb Z_2$ and $\Bbb Z_3$.

One way for $\Bbb Z_3$, Fermat's little theorem guarantees $x^5\equiv x\pmod 3$.

I think that's it:  $x^5-x=0$ can have at most $5$ solutions in an integral domain.   So there's no more options (except $\Bbb F_{2^2}$, which doesn't work.
See @rschwieb's comment).

Comment: The only other field with less than 5 elements to rule out is the field of four elements, but it's easy to see it doesn't satisfy $x^5-x$ (it satisfies $x^3=1$, hence $x^6-1$, which would not go with $x^5-x$ well.)

Comment: @rschwieb indeed,  I forgot that field,  I was thinking about $\Bbb Z_4$, which isn't an integral domain.  But as you say,  I'm safe.